# How to ask in another way: "How many bones is in the skull"

Tags: word-choice

I want to ask this question in another way. Something like

> "From How many bones is the skull made of"

or

> "how many bones is the skull consist of"

It's important to me that it will be the way that English native speaker used to ask these questions. (I'm not English native speaker as you can understand, and that why I can not to express myself and ask help)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One common way to present this information is with an **existential** construction, using *there are*.

Let's start by looking at how the answer might be expressed:

> There are 22 bones in the human skull.

To turn this into a question, we need to do three things:

1. Replace *22 bones* with the interrogative phrase *how many bones*.
2. Move the interrogative phrase *how many bones* to the front of the sentence.
3. Invert the subject *there* with the auxiliary *are* to mark the sentence as a question.

We end up with this question:

> **How many bones are there in the human skull?**

I think this is the most natural way to express it, although of course there are many ways to express something like this in English, and I don't mean to say it's the only possible answer.

The sentences you came up with are ungrammatical.  We could fix them like this:

> The skull is made up of 22 bones.　→　How many bones is the skull made up of?
>
> The skull consists of 22 bones.　→　How many bones does the skull consist of?

These are okay grammatically, but they aren't how I'd choose to express it personally.

Comment: I'd suggest not ending sentences with prepositions, but most native English speakers no longer follow that rule.

Comment: That's okay.  It was never actually a rule in the first place.

Comment: In "the resulting question", the word "there" is optional.  "How many bones are in the human skull?" or "How many bones are in a human skull?" sound natural to me.

Comment: Right, as you point out you can start with the non-existential *Twenty-two bones are in the human skull* and turn that into a question instead, which gives us the question without *there*.  There's certainly more than one way to say it!  I just wanted to give a way that I personally felt was natural sounding.

Comment: Great answer! Thank you for the answer! It helped me. I hope to see you soon again in my next questions.